# Cannot center IActiveView at IPoint in C#.NET add in

Tags: arcobjects, c#, add-in

I'm testing a simple portion of my add in and can't get it to center/pan to a specified point, I've included what is currently in my OnClick() method. No errors appear it just refreshes and nothing happens (10.1 SP1, C#.NET VS 2010).

```
IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
IActiveView actView = mxdoc.FocusMap as IActiveView;
IPageLayout pLayout = actView as IPageLayout;
ISpatialReferenceFactory srFactory = new SpatialReferenceEnvironmentClass();
int gcsCode = (int)esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_NAD1983;
ISpatialReference spatRef = srFactory.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem(gcsCode);

try
{
    IPoint point = new PointClass();
    double xCoord = 33.217918;
    double yCoord = -98.158749;
    point.PutCoords(xCoord, yCoord);
    point.Project(spatRef);
    actView.Extent.CenterAt(point);
    actView.Refresh();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: yCoord looks > 90

Comment: That seems to be my next issue, no matter what projection I put it in it puts me in the Atlantic Ocean. I believe this is because it is taking me x meters from the origin but it was my understanding that a geographic coordinate system read these coordinates differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few problems here. First [IMxDocument.FocusMap](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v0000011t000000) is read only, you can't change the extent from here, use [IMxDocument.ActiveView](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/ActiveView_Property/000v00000113000000/) instead.

Instead of projecting your point (`point.Project(spatRef);`) you need to set it by using [IPoint.SpatialReference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000020w000000) (inheritied from IGeometry class): `point.SpatialReference = spatRef;`

I have found it better to pan an envelope rather than trying to modify with CenterAt:

```
IEvelope pEnv = mxdoc.ActiveView.Extent;
pEnv.CenterAt(point);
mxdoc.ActiveView.Extent = pEnv;
```